# iis user permissions to create schedule task

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

my system Windows server 2012 - iis 8 - vs2015
i have created a page (aspx web forms , C#)
to allow the end user to specify a report ,email and select time to receive the report by email i used TaskScheduler 2.7.2 [NuGet Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskScheduler/)
to create a task schedule to do that 
the problem it works fine if i tested locally but when publish it return that error

```
{Message: "(47,4):Task:",…} ExceptionType
"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException"


StackTrace "   at Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.V2Interop.ITaskFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(String Path, ITaskDefinition pDefinition, Int32 flags, Object UserId, Object password, TaskLogonType LogonType, Object sddl)
↵   at Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.TaskFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(String path, TaskDefinition definition, TaskCreation createType, String userId, String password, TaskLogonType logonType, String sddl)↵   at Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.TaskFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(String path, TaskDefinition definition)
↵   at slnAlabraq.Query.CreateTask(Int32 ID, String Time) in C:\Sources\slnAlabraq\slnAlabraq TFS\slnAlabraq\Query.asmx.cs:line 7655
↵   at slnAlabraq.Query.SaveRepSch(Int32 id, String Time, String Reports, String Emails) in C:\Sources\slnAlabraq\slnAlabraq TFS\slnAlabraq\Query.asmx.cs:line 7812"
```

the code

```
  private string  CreateTask(int ID, string Time)
    {
        // Get the service on the local machine
        try
        {
            using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
            {
                // Create a new task definition and assign properties
                TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
                td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Send Report By Email Schedule ID" + ID;
                td.Principal.LogonType = TaskLogonType.InteractiveToken;

                // Add a trigger that will fire the task at this time every other day
                DailyTrigger dt = (DailyTrigger)td.Triggers.Add(new DailyTrigger(1));
                dt.Repetition.Duration = TimeSpan.FromDays(5000);
                dt.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                dt.StartBoundary = DateTime.Parse(Time);
                //  dt.EndBoundary = DateTime.Parse(Time).AddMinutes(20);
                // Add an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
                td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("C:\\Projects\\Report_Emails\\Report_Emails\\bin\\Debug\\Report_Emails.exe"));

                // Register the task in the root folder
                string taskName = "Send Report " + ID.ToString();
                //Error Here
                ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(taskName, td);
            }
            return "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return ex.ToString(); }
    }
```

i think it is permission matter since it works local
if it is a permission how to allow the remote user to create a task

thank you

Answer (score 0):

As above this will run under the website user, what that is setup to be.

Given you need to grant specific rights I'd suggest having a dedicated user for task management.  You can pass in this user when creating the `TaskService`, i.e.

```
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService(serverName, taskUser, taskDomain, taskPassword))
```